# How can I grab all the unique dictionary value in a particular key that is in a list but also in a column?

Tags: json, pandas, indexing, unique

I have to sort some json meta data so I used `panda.read_json` to create a dataframe. 
I called `df['tags']` to get the column I want but I am not what is the best way to proceed from here.

Within `'tags'` columns there are `174157` list type elements, within each list there are 17 dictionaries. The results I want are the unique values within the dictionary that has corresponding key of `'name' :...` for the entire tag column.

The below image is when I call `df[tag]`, I want all the unique values from `'name' :`

Edited: there are actually 16 more dictionary with 'name' in each row but you are not seeing it because of the `...`
[image]

Comment: It seems like only tag column is a panda series so I have to use multiple forloops and a empty list to check and store all the unique strings.

Comment: How does the output look like? I suspect it's a one liner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you start with something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[{'name': 'foo'}, {'name': 'foo1'}], [{'name': 'bar'}]]})
```

Then you can use

```
names = pd.DataFrame(df.a.tolist()).applymap(lambda d: d.get('name', '') if isinstance(d, dict) else '')
>>> {i: names[i].unique() for i in names.columns}
{0: array(['foo', 'bar'], dtype=object), 1: array(['foo1', ''], dtype=object)}
```

---

- `pd.Dataframe(df.a.tolist())` makes a Dataframe from the elements.
- The `applymap` extracts the name
- The dict comprehension finds the unique names.